# Can a Windows Home Server PC join an existing domain?

Tags: domain, windows-home-server

Simple question, but I've seen conflicting answers out there: Can a Windows Home Server PC join an existing domain?

Comment: Is this about joining the WHS server itself to a domain, or a PC that's connected to the WHS server? You can connect domain joined PCs up to a WHS server with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but unsupported and also in violation of the EULA.  It'll apparently run for 24 hours and then the licensing will check and put the machine into "diminished mode" until you unjoin it from the domain.